# How to use DevExpress WPF theme editor to Modify theme and use it in VS2012 prjoect?

Tags: devexpress-wpf

I am new to DevExpress WPF controls. I need to modify the theme of the controls and want to use in our project.
Please help me any help is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install WPF Theme Editor then open Wpf theme editor Select your theme from devexpress Install folder. Path may be`(C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 14.2\Components\Sources\DevExpress.Xpf.Themes`). Check your Path then start edit on control you will get xaml file, modify that style and copy past to your application..